# How can I use JavaScript to store images for offline use?

Tags: javascript, image, cordova, offlineapps

If the environment is a WebKit browser with stuff like Local Storage or Web SQL DB is there any way I can use **JavaScript** to save this image (**not** the url):

[image: Crabs]

I'd like to be able to go offline and load this image for later use from the device using something like `file:///my_app/offline_images/f71Gk.jpg` (kind of like a guaranteed cache).

**EDIT** The image could come from any website so having a php script return base64 encoded is not possible.

Comment: Would it be okay if the URL was really really long? (I'm thinking data URLs)

You could simply provide them with the data link and they could bookmark it or something.

Comment: But using a base64 encoded image is fine otherwise, right?
EDIT: Oh, yeah, canvas's toDataUrl needs the image to be on your server too.

Comment: I guess It would, but i don't know how javascript could save `http://i.stack.imgaur.com/f71Gk.jpg` and encode it. Not sure if that is the most efficient way then.

Comment: Yeah. I just realized that Canvas has its own restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using this JQuery plugin - http://dumitruglavan.com/jquery-image-cache-plugin-cache-images-in-browsers-local-storage/

Comment: Looks good, but it can only store images that are from your own server (need to code php), will update the question